# react-native-web, DatePicker component?

Tags: datepicker, react-native-web

I was hoping to use `https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker` with react-native-web but it's not compatible I think.

Is there other library that offers native datepicker look as in the image which are compatible with `react-native-web`?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Something like this will work. You can call this component instead of the native one if you are on a web platform and it will use the default web date picker.

```
export default function DateTimePicker({ value, onChange }: Props) {
  
  return createElement('input', {
    type: 'date',
    value: value,
    onInput: onChange,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem with ["react-native-date-picker"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/) but while searching for another web-compatible library I found the ["react-native-paper-dates"](https://www.reactnativepaperdates.com/) which works perfectly fine in Android iOS and Web.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is to write a native input with "date" type with the createElement function from react-native-web library like i did here with select and option tags: https://gist.github.com/orYoffe/1f5d1651bab5d477730aec317ed405fc

Then you would have native behaviour on mobile web and other native supported features

Comment: can you please give complete example how this will work ? I am new to react I couldn’t know how to do it with your solution

Comment: @RoohAl-mahaba Does my answer below help you? Let me know if you need further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I created a very similar to [@Kheva Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4570353/kheva-mann) solution, because I had some problem by the date display :

```js
    const MyWebDatePicker = () => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now()));


       return createElement('input', {
           type: 'date',
           value: date.toISOString().split("T")[0],
           onChange: (event) => {
             setDate(new Date(event.target.value))
             },
           style: {height: 30, padding: 5, border: "2px solid #677788", borderRadius: 5,  width: 250}
         })
    }
```