# DatePicker component native handling for react-native-web

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, native, react-native-web

currently we are using [react-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker) (version: "react-native-web": "^0.11.1") Do you know how to customize this library to using native design for each platform? Or do you know about some another library for this purpose?

I am aware of the similar thread [react-native-web, DatePicker component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746118/react-native-web-datepicker-component) but wondering if someone has some different solution or opinion...

Answer (score 1):

I created one for web :

```
const MyWebDatePicker = () => {
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now()));


   return createElement('input', {
       type: 'date',
       value: date.toISOString().split("T")[0],
       onChange: (event) => {
         setDate(new Date(event.target.value))
         },
       style: {height: 30, padding: 5, border: "2px solid #677788", borderRadius: 5,  width: 250}
     })
}
```