# Is there any react-native-web compatible date picker?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I'm currently working on a `react-native` project using `expo`.

A lot of the `react-native` components I'm using translate well with `react-native-web`.

I'm having a hard time finding a **date-picker library** that renders properly on both `IOS`/`Android` and `Web`.

I know I can build a custom date picker if I have to, but are they existing component already made?

Comment: state your problem clearly, and it will be good if you paste code snippet in your question.

Comment: possible resolution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746118/react-native-web-datepicker-component